# How to package WAR and JAR files into EAR in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, jboss

I'm trying to build a Struts 2 application but faces with many difficulty.

After many days of research, I had successfully built a Dynamic Web Project `strutsJSP` containing `web.xml`,`struts.xml`, `.jsp`,`.java`. Moving forward, I created an enterprise application project `earProject` and includes the war file from `strutsJSP|` and the deploy of `earProject` was a success.

However, I need to split JSP apart from action, so I created a Java Project `strutsAction` and moved my action files to `strutsAction` and tried deploying `earProject` again but this time I had the following error:

```
01:17:16,087 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /home/pktan/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments
01:17:16,105 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found ear.ear in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called ear.ear.dodeploy
01:17:16,209 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "ear.ear"
01:17:16,255 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "jspProject.war"
01:17:18,372 INFO  [com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider] (MSC service thread 1-4) Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
01:17:18,609 INFO  [com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider] (MSC service thread 1-4) Unable to locate configuration files of the name struts-plugin.xml, skipping
01:17:18,619 INFO  [com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider] (MSC service thread 1-4) Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
01:17:18,636 INFO  [com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider] (MSC service thread 1-4) Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]
01:17:18,646 INFO  [org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider] (MSC service thread 1-4) Choosing bean (struts) for class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory
01:17:18,648 INFO  [org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider] (MSC service thread 1-4) Choosing bean (struts) for class com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter
01:17:18,652 INFO  [org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider] (MSC service thread 1-4) Choosing bean (struts) for interface com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProvider
01:17:18,653 INFO  [org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider] (MSC service thread 1-4) Choosing bean (struts) for interface com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxyFactory
01:17:18,654 INFO  [org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider] (MSC service thread 1-4) Choosing bean (struts) for interface com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ObjectTypeDeterminer
01:17:18,660 INFO  [org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider] (MSC service thread 1-4) Choosing bean (struts) for interface org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.ActionMapper
01:17:18,661 INFO  [org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider] (MSC service thread 1-4) Choosing bean (jakarta) for interface org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequest
01:17:18,663 INFO  [org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider] (MSC service thread 1-4) Choosing bean (struts) for class org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerManager
01:17:18,665 INFO  [org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider] (MSC service thread 1-4) Choosing bean (struts) for interface org.apache.struts2.components.UrlRenderer
01:17:18,672 INFO  [org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider] (MSC service thread 1-4) Choosing bean (struts) for interface com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ActionValidatorManager
01:17:18,673 INFO  [org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider] (MSC service thread 1-4) Choosing bean (struts) for interface com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStackFactory
01:17:18,674 INFO  [org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider] (MSC service thread 1-4) Choosing bean (struts) for interface com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionProvider
01:17:18,675 INFO  [org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider] (MSC service thread 1-4) Choosing bean (struts) for interface com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionContextFactory
01:17:18,676 INFO  [org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider] (MSC service thread 1-4) Choosing bean (struts) for interface com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.PatternMatcher
01:17:18,682 INFO  [org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider] (MSC service thread 1-4) Choosing bean (struts) for interface org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StaticContentLoader
01:17:18,684 INFO  [org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider] (MSC service thread 1-4) Choosing bean (struts) for interface com.opensymphony.xwork2.UnknownHandlerManager
01:17:18,687 INFO  [org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider] (MSC service thread 1-4) Loading global messages from ApplicationResources
01:17:18,945 ERROR [org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher] (MSC service thread 1-4) Dispatcher initialization failed: Unable to load configuration. - action - vfs:/home/pktan/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/ear.ear/jspProject.war/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:15:39
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:436) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:447) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3269) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3865) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
Caused by: Action class [login.LoginAction] not found - action - vfs:/home/pktan/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/ear.ear/jspProject.war/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:15:39
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:426) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:370) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:487) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:278) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:204) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    ... 13 more

01:17:18,956 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/jspProject]] (MSC service thread 1-4) Exception starting filter struts2: Unable to load configuration. - action - vfs:/home/pktan/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/ear.ear/jspProject.war/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:15:39
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:449) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:447) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3269) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3865) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - action - vfs:/home/pktan/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/ear.ear/jspProject.war/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:15:39
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:436) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: Action class [login.LoginAction] not found - action - vfs:/home/pktan/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/ear.ear/jspProject.war/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:15:39
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:426) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:370) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:487) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:278) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:204) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
    ... 13 more

01:17:18,965 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Error filterStart
01:17:18,965 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Context [/jspProject] startup failed due to previous errors
01:17:18,982 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./jspProject: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./jspProject: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]

01:17:18,987 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
01:17:18,988 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 6347ms - Started 282 of 363 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 78 services are passive or on-demand)
01:17:19,189 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "ear.ear" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./jspProject" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./jspProject: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}
01:17:19,237 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment jspProject.war in 46ms
01:17:19,238 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment ear.ear in 48ms
01:17:19,240 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./jspProject: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./jspProject: JBAS018040: Failed to start context

01:17:19,242 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./jspProject" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./jspProject: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}}}
```

I have been struggling for weeks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to split actions from the web module, but if you did it then you should add dependency to your web module. Modify `manifest.mf` `class-path`.